# Year Selection is not available in react-native DatePickerIOS

Tags: datepicker, react-native-ios

Year selection is not available in `DatePickerIOS` when `datetime` mode is selected.Below is the code,

```
 <DatePickerIOS
      mode={this.props.mode}
      date={this.state.date}
      onDateChange={(date) => this.setState({ date })} 
      style={{ marginTop: 30 }}
 />
```

[image]

Any Suggestions ???

Answer (score 1):

you should use `'date'` mode to have year selection, and if you want the year and time together you can make it separate selection the date then the time.